# How to calculate modulus value for a set of values in python?

Tags: python-3.x, modulus

In one material I found one formula to calculate Precision as below

[image]

Here a and b are set of values. After many search in internet I found that modulus means remainder value or absolute value. Here I take modulus as absolute value and my python code for the above formula is as below

```
import numpy as np

def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))

a = [7,21]
b = [11, 7, 27, 21]

a_intersect_b=intersection(a,b)
print(" a_intersect_b : ",a_intersect_b)

mod_a_intersect_b=[abs(x) for x in a_intersect_b]
print("|a_intersect_b| : ",mod_a_intersect_b)

mod_a=[abs(x) for x in a]
print("|a| : ",mod_a)

numerator=np.array(mod_a_intersect_b, dtype=np.float)
denominator=np.array(mod_a, dtype=np.float)

print(" mod_a_intersect_b /  mod_a : ", numerator/denominator)
```

Here I get 2 output values. But in the material and in general the precision is a single value. If the list size increases then the output values also increases. Finally I found that I misunderstood the modulus meaning here. Guide me to get the single precision value as per the above formula. Thanks in advance.

Note: In the formula a and b are set of values. So I used list in my code. Also guide me if I use other option to mention set of values in python then I can get single precision value.

Comment: Modulus and absolute value are two very different things.  `3%2=1` shows the modulus operator (`%`) at work. The absolute takes only 1 number and returns a positive value: `abs(-3)=3`.  Based on you definition of precision I would not be surprised if what looks like the absolute value: `|a|` is supposed to do something other than return a list of the absolute values for each element in `a`.  Maybe it is looking for the size of each set?

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per you, the 2 different meaning of modulus I could understood. But the size of each set may not be the correct logic for calculating the precision up to my knowledge. So if possible try to guide me some other option.. Thanks..

Comment: All I can tell you is that taking the absolute value of each element will not give you 1 number for precision.  In set theory the double lines `|a|` can be used to mean the **cardinality** of set `a`, which is just the number of elements in that set.  I would imagine this is what's being asked for but maybe there is more information available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hoog mentioned in gis comment, the modulus operation in the case of *precision* means a [*cardinality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of some set (just a number of elements of the set), so you can define a precision as the following:

```
def precision(a, b):
    """
    a: set, relevant items
    b: set, retrieved items
    returns: float, precision value
    """
    return len(a & b) / len(a)
```

`len(a)` returns nuber of elements of the set, i.e. cardinality, `|a|` operation.

If `a`, `b` is lists, just wrap them in sets first:

```
def precision(a, b):
    """
    a: set, relevant items
    b: set, retrieved items
    returns: float, precision value
    """
    a, b = set(a), set(b)
    return len(a & b) / len(a)
```

Also, in data science and related areas precision is a metric which calculates ratio `'true positives' / ('true positives' + 'false positives')`. It's the same thing described in other terms - but standart implementations of precision won't help you.

Comment: As per the formula your answer is correct. But, I am getting different value for my input values. So, I want concentrate my input value. Thank you very much for your valuable  response.

Comment: So, what's the difference? Are `a = [7,21]`, `b = [11, 7, 27, 21]` correct examples?

Comment: As per my situation a list values always available in b list. So "return len(a & b) / len(a) " always gives me the Precision as 1.0. So only I mentioned that I want concentrate my input values. Thank you..

Comment: Precision 1.0 value is possible only if set `a` equals set `b`. That case, precision is 1.0 virtually

Comment: Yes, in this discussion we used " len(a & b) / len(a) " is nothing but set (a & b)  equals set a always. So only the precision is 1.0 always for my input. Thanks for your valuable suggestions and your time spent.

Comment: After reconsidering my input values I found that I made mistake to prepare the a & b list. Now your length based precision solution is suitable for me. Thank you very much for valuable theoretical suggestion by  Hoog and coding suggestion by Mikhail Stepanov. Thanks..

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Sometimes I get length of set (a & b) equals to set a. So that time I get precision is 1.0. Is it anything wrong when precision==1.0? or always precision should be less than 1.0? Guide me with clear points for my situation. Thanks..

Comment: If `a & b` length equals to `a`, it's okay. Note that for precision, `b` is retrieved values and `a` is relevant values, so `a` should be subset of `b` (because it's relevant to some query or so part of `b` set by definition). And if the length of `a & b` is equals lenght of `a`, it just means all `a` values is relevant. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_(information_retrieval_context)) is information retrieval (and other) definitions of precision, but you should focus on information retrieval, I guess, to avoid disambiguition.

Comment: So, yes, I have to say, precision == 1.0 is really rare for some tasks, bu it's okay. Just all retrieved correctly, no errors. And one more link about the [relevance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_(information_retrieval)), because it does not fit in this comment field :)